# Why do we only look at transitions between energy-eigenstates, when perturbing a system with an oscillating interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, absorption, born-rule

I have some doubts about the usual explanation of sharply peaked emission / absorption spectra, that one can observe when one looks at quantum mechanical systems, for example the hydrogen atom.
In short: We can calculate the transition probability between two energy eigenstates, and we see that for a given time, its amplitude is sharply peaked exactly at the energy difference between the states. That is clear. But why are "transitions" between energy eigenstates the only ones that would occur in nature in general?

In more detail:

I look at a system in the Schrödinger-picture where the time evolution is given by $H_0$. Now I perturb the system, using an oscillating time dependent interaction $H_{\text{int}} = \lambda e^{-i\omega t} H_i$.

For little $\lambda$, we can expand the solution in $\lambda$ (Dyson Series) and calculate the probability-amplitude that the system, prepared as $|n\rangle$ at $t_0$, can be found as $|m\rangle$ at time $t$. To measure this, we look at the expectation value of the projection operator $P = |n \rangle \langle n |$. Then

\begin{align}
\langle P \rangle_{|n(t)\rangle} = | \langle m | U_{\omega}(t, t_0) | n \rangle |^2
\end{align}
With $U_{\omega}$ being the solution to
\begin{align}
i \hbar \partial_t U_{\omega}(t, t_0) = (H_0 + H_{\text{int}, \omega} )U(t, t_0)
\end{align}
Employing the Dyson-series, we can calculate this probability for a given time t, and a given frequency $\omega$ of the interaction, to an order $\lambda^n$ in the strength of the interaction. The result will be sharply peaked for $\omega$ being close to $\omega_m - \omega_n$. For the interaction being subject to a time-dependent electric field (e.g. light), we interpret a change in the states as something that changes the electric field, and thus some effect that can be measured while changing the fields electricity.
As such, we can measure those sharp peaks in an absorption or emission spectrum, of atoms for example.

Now - Why can't we do the same calculation for abitrary states? Nothing prevents me from writing down, and calculating:
\begin{align}
| \langle \Psi | U_{\omega}(t, t_0) | \Phi \rangle |^2
\end{align}
For abitrary $ | \Psi \rangle $, and $|\Psi \rangle $, and this will be a correct result. But I won't see abitrary peaks in my emission / absorption spectrum, but only the peaks from the energies.

Is it because I can expand
\begin{align}
| \Psi \rangle = \sum_m \Psi_m(t) | m \rangle
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
| \Phi \rangle = \sum_n \Phi_n(t) | n \rangle
\end{align}
and thus
\begin{align}
 \langle \Psi | U_{\omega}(t, t_0) | \Phi \rangle |^2 = | \sum_{m, n} \Psi_m(t)^* \Phi_n(t) \langle m | U_{\omega}(t, t_0) | n \rangle|^2
\end{align}

I however don't see why the last expression should still be sharply peaked around distinct $\omega$-values. It's a double countable infinite sum over sharply peaked functions of $\omega$, with possibly time dependent coefficients.

Am I on the right track here, or is there another way to see this?

Comment: It might help to think about the case of resonance in classical physics too, to get some intuition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "see" the psi function (or expansion coefficients) having strong response to frequency of external wave $\Omega$ approaching difference frequencies $\omega_{nk} = \frac{E_n - E_k}{\hbar}$ from the general formulae above, as you have demonstrated. They are too general to a point where no assumption means no conclusion.

You really have to make some assumptions, such as starting with some Hamiltonian eigenfunction that oscillates sinusoidally without a perturbation, and calculate response due to external oscillating electric field (and then maybe see how this response depends on external frequency $\Omega$).

Erwin Schroedinger did this approximately in his paper *Quantisation as a Problem of Proper Values (Part IV)*, Annalen der Physik (4), vol. 81, 1926. See the English translation in the book *Collected Papers on Wave Mechanics by E. Schroedinger*, Blackie & Son Ltd., 1928.

He found out that (system starting in $k$-th eigenfunction of $H_0$), the resulting reaction of $\psi$ to oscillating perturbation is approximately the combination of two oscillations with frequencies $E_k/\hbar - \Omega, E_k/\hbar + \Omega$, and with amplitude (spatial part) that is proportional to (assuming $\Omega$ does not equal any of the difference frequencies):

$$
w_{\pm}(\mathbf r) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H'_{nk} \Phi_n(\mathbf r)}{E_n - E_k \pm \hbar \Omega}.
$$

where $H_{nk}'$ is matrix element of the perturbation Hamiltonian and $\Phi_n$'s are eigenfunctions of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$.

This means that when external frequency $\Omega$ gets close to some difference frequency $\omega_{kn}$ implied by $H_0$, correction to $\psi$ gets much greater (due to a very small number in the denominator of the implied term of the series).

One could "guess" there will be this kind of resonant response to external oscillation even without carrying out the perturbation theory calculations. For non-eigenfunction $\psi$, oscillation of dipole moment during "free oscillation", governed by $H_0$, is sum of oscillations at difference frequencies $\omega_{kn}$ with each oscillation being as strong as expansion coefficients and dipole moment matrix elements (in $H_0$ basis) determine. Exchange of energy between field and matter can happen systematically only when electric current oscillation (due to dipole oscillating) is in phase with oscillation of external electric field, and this requires very similar frequencies of both oscillations, otherwise in the long run of many periods, there is no systematic transfer and energy just oscillates between matter and field. So as long as the free oscillation is not destroyed by the perturbation too much, systematic absorption requires that external wave have frequency close to some of the $\omega_{nk}$'s. However, this is just a guess, because without doing the calculations, we don't have a good estimate of what the free oscillation changes into under the perturbation.

Schroedinger also derives from his calculations expected average of electric dipole moment in direction of axis $y$ (surprisingly, he chose a direction perpendicular to that of electric field):

$$
\langle \boldsymbol {\mu}_y \rangle = a_{kk} + 2E_0\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(E_n - E_k)a_{kn}b_{kn}}{(E_n - E_k)^2 - \hbar^2 \Omega^2} \cos \Omega t
$$
where $a_{kn}, b_{kn}$ are some matrix elements and $E_0$ is amplitude of external electric field. Similar formula would probably come out for the $x$ component, relevant for absorption.

Thus dipole moment is forced to oscillate at the external frequency $\Omega$ (as it would in a simple linear classical model), but in addition, amplitude of its oscillations depends on external frequency as if there are multiple resonant frequencies.

The model is deficient in that there is no way for the absorbed energy to dissipate and for the molecule to reach some kind of steady state in the external field. A more detailed calculation would probably show this model goes more and more into higher energy states, something that does not seem realistic if external frequency is below the ionization limit. In reality, spontaneous emission and other interactions with environment would keep the higher states unoccupied, but this is not taken into account here.

For a toy model of a two-level system, one can probably do calculations of these things without approximations of the perturbation theory, instead doing a full numerical solution. See the Rabi oscillations.

Comment: For me to understand the sections of your answer: Everything below your first paragraph relies on the assumption: "starting with some Hamiltonian eigenfunction that oscillates sinusoidally without a perturbation" - right?. 
Or do you drop the assumption from the "One could "guess"" on? Part - In that case, I reccon that the time evolution of the average dipole moment, having large values for $\Omega$ being resonant between $E_m$ and $E_n$, looks conceptually very similar to my last equation. Would you agree?

Comment: The "guess" part assumes the atom psi function is a superposition of at least two $H_0$ eigenfunctions, so there can be non-zero oscillating dipole moment. Superposition is present even in process discussed above that section, but it is assumed to be a small result of a small perturbation, not a "big superposition" existing before the perturbation comes.

Comment: I think your last equation is too general to provide any insight. Even if we apply it specifically to Hamiltonian eigenfunctions, it still does not say anything definite about effect of the external field depending on its frequency. All the interesting details are in $U$, which needs to be calculated somehow.

Comment: $U(\omega)$, contains the transition of energy-eigenfunctions to other eigenfunctions. Doesn't the same $U(\omega)$ then also contain the transition amplitudes from any state to any other state? $U$ is completely determined by how it acts on energy eigenstates, no?

Comment: Yes, $U$ is general evolution operator. But this does not mean all possible psi functions are equally probable or relevant. $H_0$ eigenfunctions are special.

Comment: "H0 eigenfunctions are special." In that the way $U$ is calculated (and approximations that have been used), it can only be used on H0 Eigenfunctions?   Then I could not write down my last equation. 

Or in the way that superpositions will not occur in nature so often? This is in line with your assumption "starting with some Hamiltonian eigenfunction"?

Comment: $U$ can be used on anything. But using your last formula on eigenfunctions or other special kets is more interesting than using it on arbitrary psi functions. $\langle \Phi_m|U|\Phi_n\rangle$ is more interesting than $\langle \psi_2|U|\psi_1\rangle$ where $\psi_1,\psi_2$ can be anything.

Comment: Ok. From what you said before, it seems like the problem you see is in the U. Now it seems that you think one won't get any insight from calculating transitions between abitrary states. 
But let's say I want to do exactly that, calculate transitions (and corresponding absorption/emission ) of abitrary states, because that's what I observe in nature - Then I have to use $U$ between abitrary psi functions. For abitrary states I still see lines (suns spectrum for example) - Then this should be resembled in $U$. We both do agree that it isn't resembled in U, but we seemingly don't agree why.

Comment: Yes, general superpositions interacting with external radiation will manifest line spectrum at eigenfrequencies. All this is captured by $U$. But $U$ is a complicated thing, it is just not possible to see what it implies without doing the calculations, either approximatively, or numerically.

Comment: We don't observe "transitions between arbitrary states". "State" $\psi$ is just mathematical tool, we can't observe and distinguish different $\psi$ in experiments with radiating gas (we can tell that some superpositions are unlikely, but not which one is realized exactly). We observe radiation, and interpret it using the Schroedinger equation and expansion coefficients in the $H_0$ basis.

Comment: I think I begin to understand: I assumed a "transition" would take place whenever there is a photon absorption, so the absorption of photons would be a good measurement for what I called "observation of transitions between abitrary states". You tell me that those measurements involving radiation are only a good measurement device for transitions between H_0 eigenstates, and that's why my last equation is too general?

Comment: "Photon absorption" is a figure of speech for the net result of a process in time that brings the atom from one $H_0$ eigenstate to some other eigenstate. This always takes time, atoms don't jump instantaneously between eigenstates. Interaction between atom and EM field is continuous, and all equations are continuous, and everything takes some time. Reaching another eigenstate is an idealized case, in general there will be a superposition of multiple eigenstates. I don't know what measurement you have in mind.

Comment: Your equation is "too general" because by itself it says nothing about how response of the system depends on $\Omega$.

Comment: I feel like we're moving in circles, because either there is a missunderstanding on my side, or we don't mean the same things by the same words (might be my problem). The comment section seems not to be the right setting (and shape) to resolve this. If you want, we could continue in chat, if not, thank you anyway.

Comment: I think it's better if you try to ask another question on SE.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we only look at transitions between energy-eigenstates, when perturbing a system with an oscillating interaction?

We don't have to.

When we calculate transition rates we typically sum over all final states:
$$
R \sim \sum_{f}|\langle \Psi_f|V|\Psi_0\rangle|^2\delta(E_0 + \omega - E_f)\;.
$$

The sum can be performed in any basis. But, why make your life difficult?

The initial state $\Psi_0$ can be any state, but how are you going to prepare a state other than a stationary state (energy eigenstate)? If the state is not stationary, how are you going to make it last long enough to hit it with a beam of probe particles? In many cases the state $\Psi_0$ has to be the ground state because there is no other way to prepare a system that won't decay before you hit it with the beam.

Comment: > *"how are you going to prepare a state other than a stationary state (energy eigenstate)?"* Superpositions of ground and excited state can be prepared by external EM perturbation. Some excited states are long-lived (fluorescence, nanoseconds), that may be plenty of time to experiment on superpositions of excited plus ground state.

Comment: OK. That was really more of a rhetorical question for OP, but thanks.

Comment: I don't need to "prepare" an energy eigenstate. We see sharp emission-lines from Na-lambs, or in the suns light, and we see absorption lines when we scan a lasers frequency through a vessel of Lithium, for example, without previously preparing any state. Following from your argument, is it then nature itself that prepares those states? And why would it do so? I can see the argument for cold environments and the ground state being favored, but besides that, I see no reason why the initial state should be an energy eigenstate.

Comment: "Following from your argument, is it then nature itself that prepares those states?" Yes. E.g., if the vessel of Lithium  is in thermal equilibrium, then the initial system is described by a density matrix like $\rho \sim \sum e^{-\beta E_i}|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$ or just by the ground state if the temperature is low enough.

Comment: (But anyways, no one if forcing you to use an energy eigenstate for the initial state--use whatever initial state you want.)